# Presentation of an algorithm

Tags: publications, citations, writing, presentation

Background:

I recently wrote a paper on the algorithm A that I developed for predicting fault events in the machine. The algorithm is tested, evaluated on a machine data set.

I developed another algorithm B and the inputs to this algorithm are the outputs from A. I tested the algorithm over the same data set of the same machine that I used to test A.

I am currently in the process of writing a paper to explain the algorithm B. However, it is required the numerical results of A to be presented along with the numerical results of B for the reader to understand the complete picture.

Question:

What is the best way to present the old results in the new paper? Should we create a separate section or is it better to write in the results section? Basically, it is just the repetition of the numerical results from the old paper (results are in tabular form). Any lead points would be helpful. Will it be considered as self-plagiarism or salami slicing?

Note: I had no idea about the development of algorithm B when I worked on algorithm A. I see algorithm B definitely extends the field of research and thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any problem with reusing your own data from a previously published article, as long as it is cited properly. This would look like:

> We evaluated algorithm B using previously published data generated by
>   algorithm A (Myself *et al*, 2010).

If the dataset is deposited somewhere along with the article describing algorithm A, it might have a DOI that you can also cite. If it isn't deposited, or hasn't been assigned a DOI, well now would be a good time to do that.

If the article describing algorithm A is more than a couple years old, nobody will think it is salami-slicing. And you only need to cite this article properly to rule out "self-plagiarism". Self-citation is an easy way to increase one's citation count, but it is definitely not unethical: you have to cite previous work relevant to your current article, even if it happens to be also from you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The data cannot be shared publicly due to confidentiality agreements

Comment: @Muk Are you able to at least cite it, for the possibility that in the future the data will be available for others to see?

Comment: @JAB. The data cannot be shared in public. Therefore, the data will not be available for the public to see other than the people who are involved in the project. I hope its clear now.